# How to change div's height

Tags: jquery

I need `divR` to be higher then `divL`, but this code doesn't work.

```
function changes(){
    var a = $('#divL').height();
    var b = a + 50;
    var c = $('#divR').height();
    if (c <= a) {$('divR').height(b);}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
if (c <= a) {$('#divR').css('height', b + 'px');
```

instead of this:

```
if (c <= a) {$('divR').height(b);}
```

you have lost  `#`

try this also, because `.height()` works fine, you have only lost the selector `#`

```
if (c <= a) {$('#divR').height(b);}
```

Comment: Alessandro too fast!  :)

Comment: $('#divR') should be :)

Comment: don't see what's wrong with using [`.height(value)`](https://api.jquery.com/height/#height-value)

Answer (score 7):

Problem is with selector... `$('divR').height(b)` should read `$('#divR').height(b)`

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try this.  This assumes you want the height in pixels.

```
function changes(){
    var a = $('#divL').height();
    var b = a + 50;
    var c = $('#divR').height();
    if (c <= a) {$('#divR').css({'height':b+'px'});}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
if (c <= a) {$('#divR').height(b);}
```